# One to many linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to fetch list of customers and theirs orders which are not deleted state.

I have a Customer entity

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Collection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
```

And I have a order entity like,

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public decimal Cost {get;set;}
  public int CustomerId {get;set;} 
  public Customer Customer {get;set;}
  public bool IsDeleted {get;set;}
}
```

Here I am struggling to fetch the list of customers and theirs orders which are not deleted.

What I have done to achieve the above requirement is,

```
var customers = (from customer in Customers
                     join order in Orders.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
                         on customer.Id equals order.CustomerId
                  where !order.IsDeleted).ToList()
```

I am getting list of customers with all their orders(including deleted = 1) when I run this query.

Please help me out to ignore the Deleted orders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this : var customers = (from customer in Customers.Where(y=>!y.IsDeleted)
                     join order in Orders.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
                         on customer.Id equals order.CustomerId
                  where !order.IsDeleted).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this differently if you want to filter the `Orders` of a `Customer` to only include those orders that were not deleted.

A new (detached) `Customer` instance, that is populated from the query result should then be created, or alternatively an anonymous object or specific "DTO" instance:

```
public class CustomerView
{
    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly List<Orders> Orders;
} 

var customers = 
    from customer in Customers
    select new CustomerView() {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        Orders = customer.Orders.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted).ToList()
    };
```

Note that since there is no `where` clause to limit the number of returned customers you are dealing with, there is an unbounded result set as the output of this query.

If you are loading a specific customer by id, you can use the following approach to "lazy load" its orders using a filter. Note: you will need to replace the `MyDbContext` with your own `DbContext` type.

```
public Customer LoadById(int customerId)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
    {
        var myCustomer = context.Customers.Find(customerId);
        if (myCustomer != null)
        {
            // Filter orders.
            context.Entry(myCustomer)
                .Collection(c => c.Orders)
                .Query() 
                .Where(o => !o.IsDeleted)
                .Load();
        }
        return myCustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. I will get single customer by his Id instead of taking all. One thing when I execute this query I got "The entity or complex type '' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." error since I am using the same Customer entity. I resolved this issue after taking the result by looping. I don't understant why entity framework is not allowing like this. Then how can we ignore the soft deleted records like this generally??

Comment: @Karthikeyan, I have updated my answer showing (1) how to use a "DTO" type class and (2) an alternative solution that may fit your problem better (see the `LoadById` example) and that performs one way of ignoring the soft deleted records when lazy loading a specific customer instance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it C# requires a `select` clause. If you add one to your suggested query `select new {customer, order}` you'll see your problem. You're extracting all orders associated with a customer via `customer.Orders`, rather than just the results of the query.